# Using Retroarch with PS1 ROMs displays at half resolution

Tags: retroarch

I'm using [Retroarch](https://retroarch.com) to play PS1 ROMs. When I open these ROMs, the resolution seems to be half that of a normal PS1 game. Is there a way to get or play with full resolution?

Comment: Hey Jacob, welcome to Arcade! Don't worry too much about your question being closed, we just need some clarification to make this a better question. Toss some more details in there, give us some info on what you mean by "half resolution", what games have you tried, steps you've already taken to resolve it, etc. Then we'll reevaluate on opening the question again. Thanks!